# JSON Parsing Android not getting next url

Tags: android, json, parsing

I'm trying to parse JSON objects from instagram feed and try to display the pictures and videos in my own layout but when I run the app, only a blank screen shows up and I also get this exception -

```
org.json.JSONException: No value for next_url
     at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:355)
     at org.json.JSONObject.getString(JSONObject.java:515)
     at com.Insta.FeedFragment.parseJsonFeed(FeedFragment.java:166)
     at com.Insta.FeedFragment.access$000(FeedFragment.java:59)
```

Following is my parsing method from FeedFragment

```
private void parseJsonFeed(JSONObject response) {
        try {
            JSONObject nexturlobj = (JSONObject) response.get("pagination");

            nxturl=nexturlobj.getString("next_url"); //Line 166 in LogCat


            JSONArray feedArray = response.getJSONArray("data");


                for (int i = 0; i < feedArray.length(); i++) {


                    JSONObject feedObj = (JSONObject) feedArray.get(i);



                    String ImageType = feedObj.getString("type");
                    if (ImageType.equalsIgnoreCase("image")) 
                    {
                        JSONObject feedObj2 = (JSONObject) feedObj.get("images");

                        JSONObject feedObj3 = (JSONObject) feedObj2.get("standard_resolution");
                        JSONObject feedObj1 = (JSONObject) feedObj.get("user");



                        FeedItem item = new FeedItem();

                        item.setId(feedObj1.getInt("id"));
                        item.setName(feedObj1.getString("username"));

                        JSONArray tagss = feedObj.getJSONArray("tags");

                        StringBuilder tags_names = new StringBuilder("");
                        for (int k = 0; k < tagss.length(); k++) {
                            tags_names.append("  #"
                                    + tagss.getString(k));
                        }

                        item.setStatus(""+tags_names);



                        item.setImge(feedObj3.getString("url"));


                        item.setProfilePic(feedObj1.getString("profile_picture"));

                        feedItems.add(item);


                    item.myurl=new ArrayList<FeedItem>();
            }
                }

            listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            tag_list_pos++;
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well, it sounds like there is no next_url field in the object you're parsing!  You'll probably have to post a complete example of this JSON in order to get help.

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't look like you are using that value in the local scope either.  For proper help, listen to @DougStevenson and post the JSON.  Maybe even FeedFragment to see what you are doing with it.  That said, as a lazy man myself, to literally avoid the problem, try `nxturl=nexturlobj.optString("next_url",);`  

Make no mistake:  **this is probably bad**, but it does get around the error.

Comment: @MiaoLiu Thanks a lot for the workaround, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

First of All, if you're developing applications for Instagram API, you are in the **SandBox** mode, which means the Instagram dataprovider, will give **only 20 of the most recent media** of any user, and in the response **there would be no "next_url".**

Secondly, for parsing JSON responses, you can use the **Gson** library and other similiar ones, instead of writing boilerplate code and reinventing the wheel.

Finally, **I have created a very descriptive sample for Instagram API, called [JuicyInsta](https://github.com/farhadfaghihi/JuicyInsta) ,as an Android application** [which I have shared on my github.](https://github.com/farhadfaghihi/JuicyInsta)

Take a look at it and It will definitely help in the areas you want.